# Convert Float to String in Arduino

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I have a few question, how do I convert Float to String?

Because my OLED display require 'String' and cannot print Float

Here is my coding

```
  WindSpeed = WIND_SPEED_20_PULSE_SECOND / ONE_ROTATION_SENSOR * (float) Rotations;
  float SpeedMPH = ((WindSpeed * 3600) / CONVERTMPH_FORMULA);
  String WindSpeedMS = WindSpeed;
  if((millis() - Start_Read_Timer) >= READ_TIME)
  {
    cli();

    WindSpeedStatus();
    
    sei();

    Rotations = 0;
    Start_Read_Timer = millis();
  }
    display.setFont(ArialMT_Plain_24);
  display.drawString(0, 20, WindSpeedMS);
  display.display();
  delay(500);
```

The error I got is:

> Compilation error: conversion from 'float' to non-scalar type 'String'
> requested

Thanks!

Comment: Unless you are going to use the `WindSpeedMS` somewhere else, otherwise Just directly use the `String()` function like  `display.drawString(0, 20, String(WindSpeed, 2))`. You might want to read more about [String()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/).

Answer (score 1):

refer to [Arduino String library](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/) as they stated that :

> **Syntax**
>
> - String(val)
> - String(val, base)
> - String(val, decimalPlaces)
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - **val**: a variable to format as a String. Allowed data types: string,
>   char, byte, int, long, unsigned int, unsigned long, float, double.
> - **base**: (optional) the base in which to format an integral value.
> - **decimalPlaces**: only if val is float or double. The desired decimal
>   places.

so instead of writing :

```
 String WindSpeedMS = WindSpeed;
```

you should write :

```
String WindSpeedMS = String(WindSpeed, 5);
```

where **5** represents the number of decimal places desired, so if `WindSpeed = 12.54545451` then `WindSpeedMS = "12.54545"`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
float SpeedMPH = ((WindSpeed * 3600) / CONVERTMPH_FORMULA);
String WindSpeedMS = String(SpeedMPH,0); // 2nd param is decimal digits
```